# Can Google Charts Linechart be modified so that points appear no matter where the cursor is on the chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts line chart and I'm looking to create the effect where focus is put on the point that corresponds to the horizontal position of the cursor.

I'm currently using the line chart with only 3 options set: Title, Width and Height. At the moment, the user must place their cursor directly on top of the data point which sits on the line that has been drawn in order to see the tooltip/data for that point.

I'm wanting to give the user an experience more like that found here:
https://au.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=BHP.AX#symbol=BHP.AX;range=1d
...where the user does not have to place their cursor ON the line to focus the data point, they simply need to move their cursor horizontally and the point that corresponds to the cursor's position on the x-axis is focused.

Has anyone been able to achieve this, either through options settings or custom code?

Cheers

Comment: an [annotation chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart) might work for you...

Comment: @WhiteHat nice one. this might come in handy in future. nbering's answer did the job though, without me having to change chart type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chart option that does what I believe you are looking for:

```
focusTarget: 'category'
```

If that alone doesn't work, check the tooltip.trigger option.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks